# Last line of batch file not running

Tags: batch-file, chef-infra, knife

I am using a batch file to make installing chef on servers a little bit less work. The last line of my code where I add the recipe seems to be completely ignored. Probably something stupid but what am I missing?

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p ip="Enter IP Address:"
set /p nodename="Enter Node Name:"
ECHO OK, installing Chef node %nodename% on %ip%
knife bootstrap %ip% -x ************ -P ************* --sudo -N %nodename% 
node-ssl-verify-mode none --no-host-key-verify 
knife node run_list add %nodename% "recipe[*********]"
```

Comment: try with `call node-ssl-verify-mode .....`

Comment: if `knife` is a batch file (`knife.bat`), then you will need to use CALL - as in `call knife bootstrap ...`

Comment: @npocmaka call node-ssl-verify-mode did not change anything, its like it just completely skips over the last line

Comment: @dbenham I am calling the batchfile from chef (powershell)

Comment: I tried adding a echo at the end and it doesn't even output that. once it finishes the knife bootstrap command it seems to exit the bat

Comment: Like dbenham said, change `knife` to `call knife`

Comment: Ok that worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, we use `.bat` wrappers for our executable Ruby scripts on Windows so to run them from another batch script you need `call knife ...`. Also you don't need the run list add most likely, unless your recipes are very broken you can set the run list during the bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that in the docs, added the recipe when to bootstrap.